# Navigation/Routing not working in Angular

Tags: angular

I am starting with Angular and tinkering with the official tutorial.

I started doing some basic navigation (a list of polls and looking up the details of each one) and it worked fine, but then I added some encapsulation (i.e. creating an interface for the poll, and injecting a service to provide the data) and then suddenly navigation no longer works.

The *app.module.ts* is

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    EncuestaComponent,
    ListaEncuestaComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: ListaEncuestaComponent },
      { path: 'encuesta/:idEncuesta', component: EncuestaComponent }]),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I have the main component, the list of polls

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-lista-encuesta',
  templateUrl: './lista-encuesta.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lista-encuesta.component.css']
})
export class ListaEncuestaComponent implements OnInit {

  titulos: string[] = ['Encuesta1', 'Encuesta2', 'Encuesta3'];

  encuestas!: Encuesta[];

  constructor(private encuestaService: EncuestaService) {
    console.log('En ListaEncuestaComponent.constructor');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.encuestas = this.encuestaService.getEncuestas();
  }
}
```

and the component for the polls:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-encuesta',
  templateUrl: './encuesta.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./encuesta.component.css']
})
export class EncuestaComponent implements OnInit {

  encuesta!: Encuesta;
 
  constructor(private activatedRouter : ActivatedRoute,
              private encuestaService : EncuestaService) {
    console.log('En EncuestaComponent.constructor');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("En EncuestaComponent.ngOnInit()");
    const routeParams = this.activatedRouter.snapshot.paramMap;
    const idEncuesta = Number(routeParams.get('idEncuesta'));
    console.log("En EncuestaComponent.ngOnInit(), idEncuesta: " + idEncuesta);
    this.encuesta = this.encuestaService.getById(idEncuesta);
  }
}
```

The list of polls is shown as it should, a list of links with the URLs as they should be (http://localhost:4200/encuesta/1, http://localhost:4200/encuesta/2). But if I go to these, it shows me again the same list of links, and in the console the log tells me that the component that has been invoked is the list of polls, not the poll component:
[image: Screenshot]

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: The HTML's
app.component.html

```
<app-lista-encuesta></app-lista-encuesta>
```

lista-encuesta.component.html

```
<p>Lista de encuestas</p>
<p></p>
<div *ngFor="let encuesta of encuestas">
<a [title]="encuesta.titulo" [routerLink]="['/encuesta', encuesta.titulo]">{{encuesta.titulo}}</a>
</div>
```

encuesta.component.html

```
<p>Id: {{encuesta.id}}
<p>Título: {{encuesta.titulo}}</p>
<p></p>
<div *ngFor="let opcion of encuesta.opciones">
{{opcion}}
</div>
```

I have also tried @H0-pe suggestion, so I removed *RouterModule* from the *imports* of *app.module.ts*, and I did add the routes to *app-routing.module.ts*, but it works the same.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ListaEncuestaComponent },
  { path: 'encuesta/:idCodigo', component: EncuestaComponent }
];
```

Comment: I try to understand.. your problem is to get the id of the poll?

Comment: @YarinLevi No, my problem is that it seems that it seems that when I go to, for example, http://localhost:4200/encuesta/1, what is being executed (as shown in the browser console) is the *ListaEncuestaComponent* and not the *EncuestaComponent*, so it does not even try to get the id.

Comment: @YarinLevi I do not follow you. I am navigating to http://localhost:4200/encuesta/1, so by the `{ path: 'encuesta/:idEncuesta', component: EncuestaComponent }])` I expected it to invoke the *EncuestaComponent* (and in fact it did work before I modified my app to play with services).

Comment: I see that you try to get - id and in your path, your parm is- idEncuesta. So you need that param will be the same.

Comment: @YarinLevi Oh, I did see that and tried it again after correcting it (now the question has been updated), but that has not been solved the issue. And I did not look like as something related, that mistake would lead to an error or a failure to find the poll, but the issue is that the wrong component is being used.

Comment: Shouldn't the routes be declared in `app-routing.module.ts` and not in `app.module.ts`?

Comment: @H0-pe I am following the (tutorial from the official angular site)[https://angular.io/start/start-routing]. Yes, the existence of an *app-routing.module.ts* puzzled me, but I am new to Angular so I have no opinion. If you think this is the issue feel free to post an answer.

Comment: Could you post your HTML files aswell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this in `app-routing.module.ts`

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: ListaEncuestaComponent },
      { path: 'encuesta/:idEncuesta', component: EncuestaComponent }]),
```

Edit:

Try putting a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` tag in your `app.component.html` and see if something happens afterwards

I created a small [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bpfabj?file=src/app/details/details.component.html) example to show you how to use the router outlet. I couldn't get the `[routerLink]` directive to work, so i just used the `href` attribute but that shouldn't change anything.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I was just updating the question with the HTMLs. I did also change the place where the configuration of the RouterModule is done, but it did not help.

Comment: The `<router-outlet>` was the missing piece, I was thinking that the process was Routing -> Component -> HTML and so I was expecting that just by setting the route, the component would be instantiated and then the HTML generated as a separated page. But in fact with routing it seems that I am using the associated component (in this case `app` itself) and there it is from where the routed component is called, in the place indicated by `<router-outlet>`.